# How to get MacOS to press a key every night at 11pm?

Tags: macos, keyboard, display, shortcut, monterey

I got a keyboard shortcut that turns down brightness on my external monitor, and I'm looking to turn down brightness automatically at 11am and turn up at 8am - is there something I could do to make Mac automatically press certain keys at a certain time?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need to press any keys?

You can set the times to do a custom night shift as needed:
[image]

And you can set a profile for that display.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the Energy Saver preferences to Sleep the computer (which will turn the display off) at a given time.

[image]